# Using batch file give exit code according to log file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I get a log file at the end of my build which indicates the status of the projects I build, I want to use this log file to give me exit code 1 when failed builds are not equal to 0.

**Log file:**

```
========== Build: 19 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

How do I create a batch file that sees if there are 1 failed(or more), and set 
%ERRORLEVEL%=1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested:

```
set "log=log.txt"

for /f "tokens=5 delims= " %%# in ('find "========== Build:" "%log%" ') do set /a fails=%%#

if %fails% neq 0 exit /b 1
```

Comment: It might be nice to capture the failure count, but the OP did not ask for it. If a simple binary Success or Failure detection is the goal, then only a single FINDSTR is all that is needed.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is set ERRORLEVEL to 0 upon success, and 1 if there was at least one failure, then a simple FINDSTR is all that is needed.

```
findstr /rc:"^========== Build: .* succeeded, 0 failed," "log.txt" >nul
```

ERRORLEVEL will be 0 if the string was found, 1 if not.

You can conditionally take action based on success or failure by using the `&&` and `||` operators

```
findstr /rc:"^========== Build: .* succeeded, 0 failed," "log.txt" >nul && (
  rem Success actions go here
) || (
  rem Failure actions go here
)
```

So if you want to simply exit with an ERRORLEVEL of 1 if there was a failure, you could use:

```
findstr /rc:"^========== Build: .* succeeded, 0 failed," "log.txt" >nul || exit /b 1
```